# What is this plant growing on Asian spider-flower?

Tags: botany, species-identification

I found a densely-clustered plant (circled in red in photo) growing on top of an Asian spider-flower. I know what Asian spider-flower looks like. I'm in Chennai, India. What type of plant is this?

[image]

(Click the Image to enlarge it)

Comment: can you post a closer picture?

Comment: Are you telling about something yellowish thread like climber plant? it may be some sort of parasitic climber, probably [*Cuscuta reflexa*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuscuta_reflexa) or [*Cassytha filiformis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassytha_filiformis).

Comment: @AlwaysConfused I added new image.

Comment: @user33380 typically plants are very difficult if not impossible to identify without close-up pictures of leaves, stems, flowers, and/or fruits. If you can take any up-close pictures, you'll likely have much better luck getting this plant identified. See [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info) for more hints regarding asking *good* [tag:species-identification] questions. Thanks.